# Find the constant $p$ and $q$ in the $\lim_{x \to \infty}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Given $$\lim_{ x\to \infty} \sqrt{x^2-x+1} -px-q=0$$ find the values of $p$ and $q$. The answer  is $p=1$ and $q= -1/2$.

I know the method is using L'Hospital’s rule and I rationalise the denominator. But I don’t know how to find the p and q. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\sqrt{x^2-x+1}-px-q=\left[\sqrt{x^2-x+1}-(px+q)\right]\frac{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}+(px+q)}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}+(px+q)}=$$

$$=\frac{x^2-x+1-(px+q)^2}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}+(px+q)}=\frac{x^2-x+1-p^2x^2-2pqx-q^2}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}+(px+q)}$$

Comment: Yes , I rationlise the denominator, but I don’t know how to find the p and q , thank you so much

Comment: @Kenneth What do you obtain by rationalisation?

Comment: @Kenneth Your rationalisation is uncorrect, check again, we have $(A-B)(A+B)=A^2-B^2$. After that we need the $x^2$ and $x$ coefficients to be equal to $0$.

Comment: Ok,I try to do this

Comment: You should note that this gives a spurious solution as well ($p=-1$).

Comment: @gimusi Then, I need to differentiate the numerator and eliminate the x? Thank you

Comment: @Kenneth We obtain teh conditions $p^2=1$ and $2pq=-1$ in order to have that the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 3):

By completing the square,

$$\sqrt{x^2-x+1}=\sqrt{\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+\frac34}=\left(x-\frac12\right)\sqrt{1+\frac3{4{\left(x-\dfrac12\right)^2}}}$$ hints you the values of $p$ and $q$ (as the second factor quickly converges to $1$). Then you can check by rationalizing the numerator.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest method consists in a substitution $x=\dfrac1u$ $\;(u\to 0_+)$ to obtain
$$f(x)=\frac1u\sqrt{1-u+u^2\strut},$$
and taking Taylor's expansion at order $2$ for the square root near $0$:
$$\sqrt{1-u+u^2\strut}=1+\frac12(-u+u^2)-\frac18(-u+u^2)^2+o(u^2)=1-\frac12u+\frac38u^2+o(u^2),$$
so 
$$f(x)=\frac1u-\frac12+\frac38u+o(u)=x-\frac12+\frac3{8x}+o\Bigl(\frac1x\Bigr).$$

Thus we obtain $p=1$, $\;q=-\dfrac12$, and we have one more information: near $+\infty$,
$$f(x)-\Bigl(x-\frac12\Bigr)>0$$
since $\frac3{8x}>0$.

Comment: $+1$ for the last part. If you have time to waste, have a look at https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/8339/teaching-limits-and-asymptotics-at-the-same-time which is (at least to me) a major concern. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Thanks. I've just read your the posts and comments in your link, and I can tell it was no wasted time! Probably I's aware of theses problem because I was in charge of maths teaching for scientific upgraders some years ago at my university.

Comment: When you think that I was teached that in 1959 !!! Cheers.